# rails active record nuances and protecting against injection attacks

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sql-injection

When I make a query...

is there any meaningful difference between using a find_by helper or not?

Are there any reasons I'm overlooking for opting for shorter lines of code when doing things like this?

```
Booking.find_all_by_user_id(1, :joins => :confirmation)

Booking.find(:all, :joins => :confirmation, :conditions => [ 'bookings.user_id = ?', 1] )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, regarding injection attacks.
The `find_by` method should be safe. However the only killer mistake is to use user input directly inside your `conditions` param when using `find` method, like doing:

```
Booking.find(:all, :joins => :confirmation, :conditions => [ 'bookings.user_id = #{params[user_id]]}'] )
```

Of course the right one is the way you did it and `find` method will filter things up.

```
Booking.find(:all, :joins => :confirmation, :conditions => [ 'bookings.user_id = ?', params[user_id]] )
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is in here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

AND

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment

Be sure to read both carefully.